# AssemblyInfo ingrored when building from GitLab-Runner

Tags: .net-core, gitlab-ci-runner

On a Windows machine there is a GitLab-Runner run from a domain user with admin rights. When I log as this user and call `dotnet build -c release` to build an ASP.NET Core app, the dll has all the information from the **AssemblyInfo.cs** file. When I do the same as part of a CI job, the produced dll is missing all this information (for example the version number).

The **AssemblyInfo.cs** file is not part of the repository, instead, it is produced by a prebuild event (using gitWCRev.exe tool). However after running some tests I can see that the **AssemblyInfo.cs** is actually generated when the job is run by the runner.

Any help as to why the file is ignored and how to overcome this issue would be appreciated.

---

At first I thought that this might be related to [Pre-build task of Visual Studio project fails in GitLab Runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60376408/pre-build-task-of-visual-studio-project-fails-in-gitlab-runner) issue, but I don't get any build errors.

On the same machine, I build a .Net Framework app which has the same AssemblyInfo setup, but is compiled using `msbuild /property:Configuration=Release` by the runner and the produced dll file has all the expected information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was partially related to the AssemblyInfo.cs file not being part of the repository.

SDK-style csproj normally don't list the files in the project, but figure them out based on the folder contents. When `dotnet build` was run, AssemblyInfo.cs wasn't present in the project directory (GitLab-Runner usually clears out files not present in the repository before starting a job/pipeline), so build tools had no idea they needed to load it. It made no difference that the file was being created by the build tools.

The solution proved to be creating an empty AssemblyInfo.cs file before running `dotnet build`. This way build tools knew they needed to compile it. Actual compilation still happened after prebuild events, so all the needed information was there.

I created the empty AssemblyInfo.cs file using PowerShell:

```
New-Item -Path "Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs" -ItemType File
```

Also, checking the build logs helped me finally figure it out. To get the build logs I've called build tools like this:

```
dotnet build -c release /flp:v=diag
```

The .Net Framework app didn't have this problem because it wasn't an SDK-style project. All the files needed for compilation were listed in the project file and build tools knew to load them, even if they were created during the prebuild event.